# WPF Validation not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I created a WPF that serves to get a serial number from a client. As part of the process, I'm trying to validate it so that the length of each segment is exactly 5 characters long and all of the characters are letters or numbers. I followed the outline given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx).

The problem is that it doesn't seem to do anything, and I followed the instructions for the submit button as well and it will submit with incorrect data, whereas it seems like it shouldn't validate if the values aren't right. Does this have anything to do with the binding `Path`? If not, why won't my fields validate?

The code for the `ValidationRule` looks like this:

```
namespace Syncagent.Installer
{
class LicenseValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if(!(value.ToString().Length == 5))
            return new ValidationResult(false,"Incorrect number of characters.");

        Regex rExp = new Regex("^[A-Z0-9]*$");
        if (!rExp.IsMatch(value.ToString().ToUpper()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,"A key may contain only numbers and letters.");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
}
```

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="wFusionKey" x:Class="SyncAgent.Installer.KeyForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SyncAgent.Installer"
    Title="FusionKeyForm" Height="158" Width="338" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid Margin="0,0,-6,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="334">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btnOkay" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Height="22" IsDefault="True" Click="btnOkay_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblFusionLicenseKey" Content="Please enter your 25-digit Fusion License Key here." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Height="26" Width="278"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFusion1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Grid.Column="1" MaxLength="5" MaxWidth="Infinity">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="/" Mode="default" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:LicenseValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsCancel="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFusion2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="76,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" MaxLength="5">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Left" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:LicenseValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFusion3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="141,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" MaxLength="5">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Left" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:LicenseValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFusion4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" MaxLength="5" RenderTransformOrigin="1.491,0.522">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Left" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:LicenseValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFusion5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="271,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" MaxLength="5">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Left" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:LicenseValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Do you see it call LicenseValidationRule and throw a false validation?  Binding path of / is odd.

Comment: No, I don't think it does anything at all. I did a binding path of '/' to test if it would change things. I feel like the binding path is wrong, but I don't know what I'm supposed to be setting it to.

Comment: You need to set the datacontext and the path.  Just set the datacontext to this and have public property for txtFusion1.  The path is the name of that public property.

Comment: I'm new to WPF, could you show me what that would look like?

Comment: Just search MSDN for .NET data binding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `TextBox` is bound to as I cannot see your code behind, however you validator seems to work ok when your `TextBox` text is bound to a string.

Here is a simple example of your Validator attached to a TextBox which is bound to a string.

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myTextToValidate;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MyTextToValidate
    {
        get { return _myTextToValidate; }
        set { _myTextToValidate = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyTextToValidate"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication11"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="89" Width="166" Name="UI">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="12" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="MyTextToValidate" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:LicenseValidationRule/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Maybe this will help track down your issue.

Comment: That's exactly it. I was trying to figure out how binding worked, this gave me a concrete example. Thank you so much!